# How to get n and e value of RSA public key?

Tags: windows-store-apps, uwp, windows-10-universal

As I know, the public part of an RSA key consists of n and e,
and I need them separately.

But `CryptographicKey.ExportPublicKey()` returns just one key,
how can I separate them? Or there is other way to export them?

The `RSAParameters` struct in .NET has `Exponent` and `Modulus` fields,
is it possible to use the `RSAParameters` struct in a UWP APP?

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to do so?

Comment: @Andrew Au To be compatible with old codes written with openssl. Openssl generate n and e separately and we used them separately.

Comment: It's not possible to use the `RSAParameters` struct in a UWP app. I haven't found a way to achieve the same with the `CryptographicKey` class (and related classes) and I'm starting to think maybe they simply don't support it. They expect the key data to be `ASN1` formatted. So we may have to format it ourselves first.